# Eslint doesn't work well with docker and Javascript on Visual Code

Tags: javascript, docker, eslint

I have the following issue with my Eslint and docker when I add a new dependency to the project I must add it in my local environment and inside the docker with npm install or yarn add, Right now I am working on a project with next js, so, Eslint is setting up by nextjs installing. Also, I have Visual Code such as Code Editor.

I'm going to share with you my configuration docker files:

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:16.17.0-alpine as xxx-xxx

WORKDIR /home/node/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN yarn

COPY . .

CMD ["yarn", "dev"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo:5.0.12-focal
    container_name: mongodb_xxx_xxx
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file: .env
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=$MONGO_USERNAME
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=$MONGO_PASSWORD
    ports:
      - '27017:27017'
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/data/db
  ts-node-docker:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      target: xxx-xxx
    image: node:16.17.0-alpine
    container_name: nodejs_xxx-xxx
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file: .env
    environment:
      - MONGO_USERNAME=$MONGO_USERNAME
      - MONGO_PASSWORD=$MONGO_PASSWORD
      - MONGO_HOSTNAME=$MONGO_HOSTNAME
      - MONGO_PORT=$MONGO_PORT
      - MONGO_DB=$MONGO_DB
    volumes:
      - .:/home/node/app
      - ./nodemon.json:/home/node/app/nodemon.json
      - ./tsconfig.json:/home/node/app/tsconfig.json
      - /home/node/app/node_modules
    expose:
      - '80'
    ports:
      - '80:8080'
    depends_on:
      - mongo
volumes:
  dbdata:
```

.eslintrc.json

```
{
  "extends": "next/core-web-vitals"
}
```

Comment: What's your actual issue?

Comment: When I don't add the dependency to my local environment Eslint shows me as an error the new dependency, but if I add the dependency only in local the docker doesn't detect that the dependency was installed. So, I have to do it in both of them.

Comment: Isn't that how Docker is supposed to work, though? You create an image of your app that is independent of your local environment. What's the use of running Docker otherwise?